# VBA (input required field and export a table to excel)

Tags: excel, vba, automation

```
    Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ie As Object, table As Object, headers()
    Dim obj As Object, startk As Long, endk As Long
    Dim headersTop As Object, ele As Object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    headers = Array("OI", "Volume", "IV", "Bid/Ask", "Last", "Strike", "Last", "Bid/Ask", "IV", "Volume", "OI")  '<== This is second row of headers

    startk = InputBox("Min strike price:")
    endk = InputBox("Max strike price:")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

        .document.getElementsByClassName("mss_list val valstart").Value = "startk"


        .document.getElementsByClassName("mss_list val valend").Value = "endk"

        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        .document.getElementsByName("load").Item.Click

        Set table = .document.querySelector("#option")
        Set headersTop = .document.querySelectorAll("#option tr:first-child th")  '<== This is top row of headers which involves merged table cells. I prepare the excel sheet in the same way in the code below.
        ws.Range("A1:D1").Merge
        ws.Range("A1").Value = headersTop.Item(0).innerText  ' CALL
        ws.Range("E1:G1").Merge
        ws.Range("E1") = headersTop.Item(1).innerText  '< Date
        ws.Range("H1:K1").Merge
        ws.Range("H1") = headersTop.Item(2).innerText  '< PUT
        ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, td As Object, tr As Object
        r = 3
        For Each tr In table.getElementsByClassName("tdrow") 'loop the rows below the headers by using class name to isolate
            c = 1
            For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td") '< loop table cells i.e. columns of rows
                ws.Cells(r, c) = IIf(c Mod 4 = 0, "'" & td.innerText, td.innerText)  '< If column number is 4 or 8 then add "'" in front so formatting preserved
            c = c + 1
            Next
            r = r + 1
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Above is my code to extract the data from [hkex](https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Futures-and-Options-Prices/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures-and-Options?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI) where I want to specify two strike prices and get the details of those options. The process is 1) enter two strike prices. 2) press "enter" to get the database on notice 3) click the "load" button for a number of times for all strike price showing up. I failed to do so with my code. I hope to get any advice from you.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection which you need to index into e.g. getElementsByClassName("mss_list val valstart")(0).value = "xyz"